# double.Parse doesn't work with some country apparently

Tags: c#, math, rounding

Basically, I have this really simple calculation:

```
int bTaxPrice = int.Parse(prices[wep]);
double t = double.Parse("1." + taxes);
double price = Math.Round(t * bTaxPrice);
```

I'll give you an example for how the calculation should work, lets say `t=1.1` and `bTaxPrice=1279`, then `1.1*1279 = 1406.9`, but since I'm rounding the result the price equals 1407.

For some users from another country (Denmark) that are using my C# Winforms program are experiencing a problem that causes the number not to round, but to add the last 2 digits after the decimal point.

Our result for the calculation above was 1407, for them it's 140690.

I read about it in the internet, and some countries have something special with there decimal point.

What is a good fix for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, many countries use a comma for their decimal separator.
If you want to use the dot as a separator, use the invariant `CultureInfo`:

`double.Parse("1." + taxes, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 2):

Some countries use a comma as decimal separator. You could fix this by supplying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the `double.Parse` method.